Force Certbot to overwrite certificate
I want certbot to overwrite a certificate no matter what. But any time it runs, it creates a new directory with a suffix like -0001. That breaks everything on my system.
certbot certonly --cert-name mycert-name --standalone --server https://ourcertserver/ejbca/acme/directory 
--email "ourmail@domain.com" --key-type rsa --rsa-key-size 4096 -d myserver.intra.net -d myaltname.intra.net 
-d my2altname.intra.net -d my3altname.intra.net -d my4altname.intra.net --http-01-port=8180 -vvvv

Expected result:
The cert and key are overwritten.
Actual result:
I get an new folder archive/mycertname-0001, then -0002 and so on.
Alternative solution: Make certbot simply forget the previous cert. But I haven't found any way for this either.

Are you sure the certificate is being created in a folder called archive instead of the original certificate being moved into that folder? Are you revoking the old certificate?

@Ramhound Yes. The certbot creates only symlinks in the live folder, which point on the archive files.
